# Java REST API throws error "org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_PROPERTIES"

Tags: java, gwt, jackson, glassfish

My Java-backend running on a newly setup Debian 9 machine does not work properly anymore. Some calls are working, others fail with this error stack:

> org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_PROPERTIES
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.internal.ResponseWriter.rethrow(ResponseWriter.java:278)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.internal.ResponseWriter.failure(ResponseWriter.java:260)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.process(ServerRuntime.java:509)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:334)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:305)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1154)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:473)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:427)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:388)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:341)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:228)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:686)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:501)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:557)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1086)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:428)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1020)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.RequestLogHandler.handle(RequestLogHandler.java:68)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:370)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:489)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:960)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1021)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:865)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:240)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:668)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:52)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

It does not give me a single hint where in my code this is happening, on other maschines, with the same import this is working.

I cannot find any difference in the used libraries compared to the server where the project is working fine. Also the same java version is used on the server and on my machine.

Anyone with any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's most likely a classpath issue, where Glassfish somehow picks up an older version of Jackson. The [ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_PROPERTIES](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/MapperFeature.html#ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_PROPERTIES)
 field was introduced in Jackson 2.5, so look for earlier versions in the classpath.

Try logging the Jackson version by finding a class that implements the [Versioned](https://static.javadoc.io/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core/2.9.2/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/Versioned.html) interface (e.g. `ObjectMapper`). That should tell you whether the classpath theory holds up.

Comment: Hi Henrik, thanks for your answer. I removed all dependencies of jackson from the project and still the same error occurs, the version of jackson is 2.8.7, without any Jackson-libs in the project ...
The same project works on Windows dev maschines and the linux server, just not on my Debian PC.

Comment: any other ideas? I already tried using a different version of eclipse but nothing helps ...

Comment: Perhaps the stuff mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35769351/13075)?

Comment: I finally fixed this, not 100% sure what the issue was. I removed all jersey and jackson libs and readded them one by one. without adding `jackson-core` and `jackson-databind` libs it is working fine now ... thanks

Comment: @newnoise: All right. Good to hear. My guess is that the order of the jars on the classpath changed during your re-addition, and you now have the newest version of Jackson "in front".

Comment: I did not even add the jars to the classpath, just back to the `WEB-INF/lib`-folder ...